# An equivalent definition of a symmetric operator on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces

Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a real Hilbert space and $|\cdot|$ its induced norm. Let $A: D(A) \subset H \to H$ be an unbounded linear operator that is densely defined. One says that

- $A$ is *symmetric* IFF $\langle Au, v \rangle = \langle u, A v \rangle$ for all $u,v\in D(A)$.
- $A$ is *self-adjoint* IFF $D(A) =D(A^*)$ and $A^*=A$.

I would like to verify a claim in *Remark 7* at page 193 of Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> $A$ is symmetric IFF $A \subset A^*$, i.e., $D(A) \subset D(A^*)$ and $A^*=A$ on $D(A)$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you please have a check on it?

---

1. $\implies$

Let $A$ be symmetric. We have
$$
D(A^*)  := \{v \in H : \exists c >0 \text{ s.t. } |\langle v, Au \rangle | \le c |u| \quad \forall u \in D(A)\}.
$$

First, we prove $D(A) \subset D(A^*)$. Let $v \in D(A)$. By symmetry of $A$ and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$
|\langle v, Au \rangle | = |\langle Av, u \rangle | \le |Au| \cdot |v|
\quad \forall u\in D(A).
$$

Then $v \in D(A^*)$.

Second, we prove $A^*=A$ on $D(A)$. We have
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle Au, v \rangle &= \langle u, Av \rangle \quad \forall u,v\in D(A), \\
\langle Au, v \rangle &= \langle u, A^* v \rangle \quad \forall u\in D(A), v\in D(A^*). \\
\end{align*}
$$

Because $D(A) \subset D(A^*)$,
$$
\langle u, Av \rangle = \langle u, A^* v \rangle \quad \forall u,v\in D(A).
$$

Let $v \in D(A)$. Then
$$
\langle u, Av \rangle = \langle u, A^* v \rangle \quad \forall u\in D(A).
$$

Because $D(A)$ is dense in $H$, we get $Av = A^*v$.

2. $\impliedby$

By definition of $A^*$,
$$
\langle Au, v \rangle = \langle u, A^* v \rangle \quad \forall u\in D(A), v\in D(A^*).
$$

Let $A \subset A^*$. It follows from $D(A) \subset D(A^*)$ that
$$
\langle Au, v \rangle = \langle u, A^* v \rangle \quad \forall u\in D(A), v\in D(A).
$$

It follows from $A^*=A$ on $D(A)$ that
$$
\langle Au, v \rangle = \langle u, A v \rangle \quad \forall u\in D(A), v\in D(A).
$$

Comment: $A$ is symmetric iff $A \preceq A^*$ (you have to allow for non-strict inclusion.)